# how to convert NPZ file to text file using python

Tags: python, numpy, text-files

**Use this simple code to convert NPZ file to text file.**

```
import numpy as np
import sys
data = np.load("file_name.npz")
print(data.files)
row = data.files
np.set_printoptions(threshold=np.inf)
print(data['arr_0'])
sys.stdout=open("test.txt","w")
for i in row:
    print("--------------------------")
    print(data[i])
sys.stdout.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#import packages we need
import numpy as np
```

---

### Create example NPZ file

```
myarray = np.array([0,1,2,3])
np.savez('npzfile.npz',array0=myarray) # array0 will be the name with which you can retrieve myarray
```

---

### Read it in

```
data = np.load('npzfile.npz')
data['array0'] # use array0 key to retrieve myarray
```

Result will be:

```
array([0, 1, 2, 3])
```

Which is a numpy array:

```
type(data['array0'])
```

Outputting `numpy.ndarray`.

---

### If you don't know how NPZ was saved

You can do `data.files`. If you use the example NPZ above, this'll output `['array0']`. This can help you knowing what are the names of the array when using `data[name_of_array]` (ie `data[array0]` above).